# Building a problem unitary circuit for QAOA on Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, optimization, qaoa

I am trying to build a circuit for QAOA that solves a Traveling Salesman's Problem, which can be represented as a complete graph with 4 nodes. After formulating the problem as a QUBO and mapping it into the Ising model, I got what partially looks like:

```
...
- 65.38145411333922 * IIIIIIIIIIZIIIII
...
+ 16.08207839539523 * IIIIIIIIIIIIZIIZ
...
+ 0.2072297158017044 * IIIIIIIZIIIIIIZI
...
```

As you can see, there are several terms that only involve with single Z operation. As far as I understand with regards to QAOA, this can be built in a circuit with a $R_z$ gate on its corresponding qubit with a given parameter angle. However, I soon realized that in Qiskit, $R_z$ requires a different parameter type from the rest of other rotations gates, namely, the "phi." And my implementation of running the circuit indeed returns an error, stating

```
CircuitError: "Invalid param type for gate rz."
```

Can anyone help me with assigning a valid parameter to the $R_z$ gates in Qiskit?

Comment: Could you please provide whole code? Also note that QUBO is firstly converted to Ising Hamiltonian which is the expression in your question and only afterwards the Hamiltonian is exponentiated (exponential of $iZ\theta/2$ is $Rz(\theta)$ gate).

Comment: @MartinVesely Hey Martin, it turned out that I had made a dumb mistake on my code, putting single angle value instead of a set of angles which is a correct input for the function. Now the error has been fixed, but I really appreciate your comment.